# Exchange Transition 2003/2010: Mailbox on 2K3 server cannot be accessed by smartphone

Tags: exchange-2010

Exchange 2003 to 2010 transition testing continues - I am able to access 2003 and 2010 mailbox accounts on OWA. When I try to access a mailbox still on the 2003 server via my android it is unable to connect. It says unable to verify password. If I try to create a new account on my phone for a mailbox account on 2003, it hangs at 'verify server settings'.

I am sure I left a step out somewhere. What controls smartphone access from 2010 to 2003?

Comment: I believe I had a similar issue in the past but once you begin migration, the 2003 mailboxes will have a problem being accessed on smartphones. There are a few factors and you're not really sharing everything you did. Activesync pops to mind as well as possibilities of DNS routing issues. Did you check eventvwr?

Comment: did you have a 2003 frontend/backend topology in place before you put in 2010?

Comment: @Rex - We did not have FE/BE Exchange 2003

Comment: @user2347237 I dont think activesync will work since the mailbox is on a 2k3 server? The smartphone is using the 'mail.domain.com' address as the server. Will 2k10 forward the smartphone request to a 2k3 server?

Comment: I can see that my Exch 2010 server authenticates my request, but my phone reports 'Unable to connect to server'

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the requirement for SSL on the 2003 Exchange virtDir (and/or the Microsoft-Server-Activesync virtDir). Also, if you have forms based authentication enabled on the 2003 servers, you may need to disable that as well and remove the basic authentication method. Exchange 2010 needs to proxy the connection from the mobile device to the Exchange 2003 servers and it does not use SSL to do the proxy. The initial connection between the mobile device and Exchange 2010 should remain encrypted over SSL.

The internal proxy connection between 2010 and 2003 represents a minimal security risk as it should all be internal traffic from that point.

edit:
In Exchange 2003/2010 coexistence, ActiveSync is proxied over HTTP, not redirected. Found [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/12/08/3408985.aspx) from a while back which details it pretty well and mentions again the need to not use basic authentication but have windows/kerberos authentication enabled on the EAS virtual directory.

Comment: I disabled FBA on the Exch 2003 server and that wasn't a magic fix. I tried that alone because I knew exactly where that setting was. Where am I disabling the SSL? on IIS on the 2003 server?

Comment: Looking through the folders on the Exch 2003 IIS I see that none have selected 'Require secure channel(SSL)'.

Comment: If you had forms based authentication enabled, you will also need to change the authentication method for the Exchange virtual directory to remove basic authentication. Just updated the answer above to include that info.

Comment: Maybe a potential workaround or some insight further in to whats going on: If I connect my phone directly to a mailbox thats been moved to the Ex2010 server ( I have a temp public IP address to get me to that server), I can access mail over my phone. That may be more of verification than anything else...I guess the problem is the redirection from 2010 to find the mailbox on 2003.

Comment: It's not redirected, it's proxied. Added more info to answer above.

Comment: very helpful! I think I got it. I tested it really quick and it worked. I was able to access a 2003 mailbox via smartphone. ALL I had to do was go in to the 2003 Server IIS > Expand Default Web Site > right Click Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync virtual Dir > Directory Security Tab > Click Edit under Authentication and Access control > tick integrated windows authentication. I want to test more in the morning before I consider this a success.

Comment: Just wanted to add on more thing as my transition continues...I still have both 2k3 and 2k10 in place. Some smartphones will not connect if the users mailboxes were on 2k3. Some iphones would proxy to 2k3 some wouldnt. Some android phones would, some wouldnt. Blackberry's wouldnt at all. If I got a complaint from a user they couldnt access their email on their smartphone I moved their mailbox to 2k10. So far in every case their mail started working once the move was complete. They didnt have to make any changes.